# What is the output of the array / pointer in this c code

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, output, ascii

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
     {

     char*str="↔⬆12345";
     printf("%d",*str );
     return 0;
   }
```

please help me to find the output of the given code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file is encoded using UTF-8, the string consists of these bytes in hex:

```
E2 86 94 E2 AC 86 F0 9F 99 82 31 32 33 34 35
```

On a system where `char` means `unsigned char`, the first char is 226.

On a two's-complement system where `char` means `signed char`, the first char is -30.

On a one's-complement system where `char` means `signed char`, the first char is -29.

This value will be promoted to an equivalent `int`, passed to `printf`, and printed.